# Intellij, run play framework app in a given port

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, playframework, sbt

I have a Scala app with Play Framework.
To run the app I can open a terminal, run `sbt` and then:

`run`

This will run the app on port 9000 (default port).
If I want to run on a different port, let's say in port 9001 in `sbt` I can do:

`run 9001`

What if I want to do the same in Intellij?
I can create a new `Configuration`, click on `sbt task` and in `Tasks:` enter `run`.
This will run the app in port 9000.

If instead of just `run` I put `run 9001` (like when running within `sbt`) the app keep using the port 9000.

So my question is how can I start on a different port using `sbt task` in Configurations?

Comment: Did you try putting quotes like `"run 9001"`?

Comment: Oh my god ... It was so easy, thank you !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were to run it from CLI (not in SBT console), you would write it `sbt "run 9001"` because `run 9001` is a single command from SBT point of view.

IntelliJ expects it the same way: `"run 9001"`.